# Can you configure velocity to use a toolbox file from the classpath?

Tags: spring, velocity

I'm using spring with a VelocityViewResolver configured by Spring

```
<bean id="velocityViewResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".vm" />
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true" />
    <property name="toolboxConfigLocation" value="/WEB-INF/velocityToolbox.xml" />
</bean>
```

This works if the velocityToolbox.xml file is under WEB-INF ; however I'm trying to put it in the classpath. Is there a way to do it ?

I've tried specifying toolboxConfigLocation as "classpath:/wherever/velocityToolbox.xml", but it does not find the resource, and I end up with no toolbox configured, and a NPE at runtime (for some reason, it seems like the code expect the location to start with a '/', or add the '/' itself before looking for the resource).

Given that the resource is located using ServletContext.getResourceAsStream, with the content of the toolboxConfigLocation property prefixed by a "/", is there a way I can "define" a resource in my spring config that would somehow 'point' to an actuall classpath resource ?

Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to be a full path, eg:

```
/WEB-INF/classes/com/myapp/resources/toolbox.xml
```

The ServletToolboxManager#getInstance(ServletContext context, String toolboxConfigLocation) method is used to generate a ToolboxManager configured with the toolbox in order to create the ChainedContext used in the VelocityToolboxView.

This method pre-appends the path with a '/' if one does not exist, and then uses ServletContext#getResourceAsStream(String path) to read it in.

With this in mind, you'll have success if you set it as a full path from the context root.